# Will this UPDATE statement work?

Tags: sql, sql-update

```
UPDATE table1
 SET variable1 = (SELECT variable1 FROM table2),
     variable2 = (SELECT variable2 FROM table2)
WHERE table1.variable3 = table3.variable3;
```

Basically I am writing a query to update table1 using the data in table2. However the where statement is using table1 and table3. I am wondering if this will work or do I have to use WHERE statement after SELECT to create some constraints.

Comment: This will only work if table2 contains exactly one row. BTW what is table3 ?

Comment: which database, the syntax may be differnent in differnt databases

Comment: It will error on *any* DBMS, since table3 is not in the range table.

Answer (score 4):

No, because you have no explicit guarantee that your nested subqueries return only a single row.
**EDIT:** And, per @wildplasser comment to the question, it will also fail because table3 is not `JOIN`ed properly (at all)

Consider this change... perhaps not correct for your goal but **functional** because it returns only a single row from each subquery:

```
UPDATE 
    table1
SET 
    variable1 = (SELECT TOP 1 variable1 FROM table2)
    ,variable2 = (SELECT TOP 1 variable2 FROM table2)
FROM
    table1
JOIN 
    table3
        ON table3.variable3 = table1.variable3
```

Comment: you should really be using proper join syntax for table3

Answer (score 2):

No, but it could.

```
UPDATE table1
    SET variable1 = (SELECT TOP 1 variable1 FROM table2),
        variable2 = (SELECT TOP 1 variable2 FROM table2)
FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table3 on table1.variable3 = table3.variable3
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work. (Most?) RDBMS will allow you to do a JOINed UPDATE, though. That's generally a better way to approach these problems IMO:

```
UPDATE table1
SET variable1 = table2.variable1,
    variable2 = table2.variable2
FROM table1
JOIN table3 ON
    table1.variable3 = table3.variable3
--Presumably there's only 1 row in table2, with no JOIN criteria
CROSS JOIN table2;
```

which would `UPDATE` all rows in `table1` that are also in `table3` to the values in `table2`